# How Repeat ThreeJS Matcap use fragmentShader Texture

Tags: javascript, three.js

here is vertex and fragmentshader material :

```js
material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

uniforms: {
    textureMap: { type: 't', value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'img/matcap/green.jpg' ) },
    normalMap: { type: 't', value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'img/normalmap/stamp.jpg' ) },
    normalScale: { type: 'f', value: 0.5 },
    texScale: { type: 'f', value: 5 },
    useSSS: { type: 'f', value: 10 },
    useScreen: { type: 'f', value: 0 },
    color: { type: 'c', value: new THREE.Color( 0, 0, 0 ) }
},
vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent,
side: THREE.DoubleSide

} );
```

I want repeat texture use like this

```js
material.uniforms.textureMap.value.wrapS = material.uniforms.textureMap.value.wrapT = 
THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;

material.uniforms.normalMap.value.wrapS = material.uniforms.normalMap.value.wrapT = 
THREE.RepeatWrapping;
material.uniforms.normalMap.value.repeat.set( 20, 20 );
```

but not work in three.js why? how fix it 
thanks all friends!

Answer (score 0):

By default the texture are Clamp To Edge means no wrapping to zero. Your main texture is Clamp TO Edge repeat and normal texture is Repeat Wrapping probably you normal map texture quality is not so bright to make a difference try to revert the thing or texture ( means make some bright normal map texture or dull texture map any).

your approach is correct it seems. One more thing which you can do to increase readability:

```
            var textureMap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'img/matcap/green.jpg' );
            var normalMap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'img/normalmap/stamp.jpg' )
            textureMap.repeat.set(20,20);
            normalMap.repeat.set(10,10);
            //then shader code
```